# Are multiple gcm_sender_ids mandatory for multiple site web push?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, web-push, chrome-gcm, web-notifications

We are a company that operates about 500 large and small sites.
(Self, outsourcing ...)

We are trying to attach a notification to these sites.
I know that when I sign in with my Google Developer Center account and get the gcm service, I get one `gcm_sender_id`.

1. Is there anything wrong with using this as a 'web push' on 500 large and small sites with one `sender_id` issued?
   If you send a web push to each member at 500 sites at the same time, it could be hundreds of thousands to millions.
   (Of course the maximum amount you can request at a time is 1000 times.)
   I would like to know if there are any problems with the addition of such restrictions.
2. We see similar administration agencies, and they seem to be issuing different `gcm_sender_id` to each new site.
   Can this issue multiple `gcm_sender_id` in one Developer Center account?
   I asked him a little bit, and he said it was automated.

If you are a member of a management agency site, you can create a site by simply registering the site, and `gcm_sender_id` is automatically issued in real time.

In that short amount of time, I would like to sign up for a Google Developer Center account and give me one `gcm_sender_id` right away, and wonder if `gcm_sender_id` will be issued right away.
(The company I mentioned is not affiliated with Google.)

Also, if you want to create a web push for 500 sites, why do you have to issue `gcm_sender_id` differently or why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same sender ID for multiple *domains*.

The problem is that in case of abuses it might be difficult to identify the actual sender among the various customers (if each website belongs to a different company). So I would say that the best approach is to create a different sender ID for each customer (as the agency has suggested).
On the other hand, if the same customer has a domain with many subdomains, for example, you can use a single sender ID, since the sender / customer is actually the same.

However, I recommend that you use **VAPID** ([standard](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-vapid-02)) to automate the registration process of the sender with Firebase Cloud Messaging (previously GCM). The use of a sender ID is a legacy proprietary method and might get deprecated in the future.

Read [this article](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/web-push-interop-wins) to get started with VAPID, or use a web push service  that supports VAPID automatically and saves you a lot of time and trouble.